# Media Image Loading Indefinitely

Tags: sdwebimage, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm currently using JSQMessagesViewController for showing the image bubble and SDImageWeb to download the images and display it. The way I'm doing this is that someone would send a person a text message containing a url and the sender and receiver would both check for that and if it matches display and download an image from the url. It would show up as an image bubble rather than text message.

#### Expected behavior

When sending media images or receiving I should have the images eventually load (there's a loading animation on the images). After it loads, I should easily see it next time I go on without loading since it's cached.

#### Actual behavior

When receiving media images, sometimes it loads right away but sometimes if it tries to load it will load indefinitely. I know it is done downloading because if I trigger a reload of collection view either through messaging something or going back to main view and coming back to the same viewcontroller it will show up. If I close my app and restart it, the pictures I have finished downloading should show up instead it will show up as loading again for indefinitely. It only happens to the ones most recent, the old ones are all okay.

#### Steps to reproduce

- Use SD image to download images for media bubbles
- Send images possibly on a slower internet where it takes more than a few milliseconds to load

#### Fixes I tried

The way I did this was I would receive a message containing a url and I download it and return back a JSQMessage that contains a media bubble. I tried reloading the collectionview at that index or reloading entire collectionview with a completion block in SD web but it ends up with a endless loop.

I'm not sure if this is currently a fault of SDweb or JSQMessageController. I have tried using Kingfisher as an image caching and downloading with relatively the same results.

#### Code

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    let message = self.messages[indexPath.item]

    if (message.body!.rangeOfString ("An image https://x.com/uploads/") != nil) {

        let types: NSTextCheckingType = .Link

        let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)

        guard let detect = detector else {
            let JSQTypeMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: message.from, senderDisplayName: message.from, date: message.date, text: message.body)

            return JSQTypeMessage
        }

        let matches = detect.matchesInString(message.body!, options: .ReportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, message.body!.characters.count))

        var stringUrl:NSURL?

        stringUrl = matches[0].URL!

        let tempImageView = UIImageView(image: nil)
        tempImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(stringUrl, completed: nil)

        let photoImage = JSQPhotoMediaItem(image: tempImageView.image)

        // This makes it so the bubble can be incoming rather than just all outgoing.
        if !(message.from == self.senderId) {
            photoImage.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = false
        }

        let message = JSQMessage(senderId: message.from, displayName: self.senderDisplayName, media: photoImage)
        return message
    }

    let JSQTypeMessage = JSQMessage(senderId: message.from, senderDisplayName: message.from, date: message.date, text: message.body)

    return JSQTypeMessage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you what to do is use the completion handler that is built into sdWebImage

```
tempImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(stringUrl, completed: {
//Set your image in here because you know that you have an image
// Then reload the cell
Self.tableView.reloadCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)


})
```

Comment: I tried that with the collection view but it ends up an endless cycle since it calls the same function over and over again. I checked if the image is loading from cache or from the internet to prevent this endless loop but it doesn't seem like the statement works. Thanks though :)